# Win10 browsers cannot connect to http sites

Tags: internet-connection, http, windows-10

I have been raking through site by site on my phone to find a solution to this but to no avail.

Context: My Windows 8.1 ASUS S551L updated to Windows 10 and the first issue was lack of WiFi (zero connections). I solved that with a posted reg edit fix.

Unfortunately now I've encountered this fail: I can't access any sites that are not HTTPS. For the http /unsecured pages, I get the error "`Unable to access the network`"  with "`ERR_NETWORK_ACCESS_DENIED`"

Things I've tested that don't do anything:

- Turning off Windows Firewall
- Turning off Windows Defender ('real protection')
- Adding Google  Chrome to exclusion lists
- Deselecting options in LAN settings (Internet Options)
- Lowering all Internet Options security levels

Not entirely sure whether my approach would have led anywhere but now I'm just lost and fairly frustrated that this is happening.

Pre-win10 this was obviously not an issue.

Comment: I have the same issue. Reverted to Windows 7 until there's a fix for this issue.

Comment: Have you tried using a different web browser? Edge (the new Internet Explorer) is installed by default. Does it exhibit the same behavior as Chrome? Are you running anything like PeerBlock that works to block certain IP ranges (usually used for Ad blocking or Malware blocking or P2P privacy or privacy in general)? What about Symantec or Norton products that might have an integrated firewall?

Comment: Is this for all browsers? Anything odd in hosts file? Is this a home network?